# DAX Power BI 445 Calendar week Grouping

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
Date = 
VAR MinYear = YEAR ( MIN (report1585679325399[Actual Arrive Time.1]))
VAR MaxYear = YEAR ( MAX ( report1585679325399[Actual Arrive Time.1]) )
RETURN
ADDCOLUMNS (
    FILTER (
        CALENDARAUTO( ), 
        AND ( YEAR ( [Date] ) >= MinYear, YEAR ( [Date] ) <= MaxYear )
    ),
    "Calendar Year", "CY " & YEAR ( [Date] ),
    "Month Name", FORMAT ( [Date], "mmmm" ),
    "Month Number", MONTH ( [Date] ),
    "Weekday", FORMAT ( [Date], "dddd" ),
    "Weekday number", WEEKDAY( [Date] ),
    "Quarter", "Q" & TRUNC ( ( MONTH ( [Date] ) - 1 ) / 3 ) + 1
)
```

[image]

Above is the code I am using for my dates table. I want to add Fiscal week that starts on Saturday, i.e. week 1 of 2020 would consist Jan 1-3rd. Week 2 would be Jan 4-10. There will be 53 weeks for 2020.

I also want to add a column that says the start date and end date for each week. ie week 1, 01/01/2020, 01/04/2020.

The format would be a 445 calendar. Jan 4 weeks, Feb 4 weeks, Mar 5 weeks, Apr 4 weeks, May 4 weeks, June 5 weeks etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a week starting on a Saturday but the [`WEEKNUM` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/weeknum-function-dax) can do weeks starting on Sunday or Monday and starting on Sunday lines up with your `Weekday number`.

To get the start date for the week starting on Saturday you can `Date - Weekday number` except for the first week where you'll want to take Jan. 1.

```
WeekStart = MAX ( [Date] - [Weekday number], STARTOFYEAR ( [Date] ) )
```

Comment: Thank you Alexis! I actually found a code online and I've been using it to group my fiscal week and date. However, the code is very long and its slowing down my power bi. I only need all Fiscal cal fields and fiscal week fields.  

https://github.com/sql-bi/DaxDateTemplate/blob/master/DAX%20Date%20Template.pbit